# Including multiple values in a column in KQL

Tags: kql, o365security-compliance

I am trying to figure out a way to return multiple values in a single column in KQL in Microsoft 365 Defender. For example, if I am trying to output multiple file names from the EmailAttachmentInfo schema, how would I go about doing so?

```
EmailAttachmentInfo
| where FileName matches regex "Interesting_File_\d+\.zip"
| project FileName
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
// Data sample generation. Not part of the solution
let EmailAttachmentInfo = 
datatable(customer_id:int, FileName:string)
[
    1 ,'file1.zip'
   ,1 ,'file2.zip'
   ,1 ,'file1.zip'
   ,1 ,'file3.zip'
   ,1 ,'file2.zip'
   ,2 ,'file3.zip'
   ,2 ,'file3.zip'
   ,2 ,'file4.zip'
];
// Solution starts here
EmailAttachmentInfo
| summarize make_set(FileName), make_list(FileName) by customer_id
```

| customer_id | set_FileName | list_FileName |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | ["file1.zip","file2.zip","file3.zip"] | ["file1.zip","file2.zip","file1.zip","file3.zip","file2.zip"] |
| 2 | ["file3.zip","file4.zip"] | ["file3.zip","file3.zip","file4.zip"] |

[Fiddle](https://dataexplorer.azure.com/clusters/help/databases/Samples?query=H4sIAAAAAAAAA4WQP0sDURDE+wfvO0yXBI4ciVaRFIIKNmksRcIm2cstvj/H273C4If31ARSHLrlb2YWZuoaD2QEpdgFxpETFzLJaY5NNnRUDLmBtQzNof9WvAtseIwk4d6M9m3kZM+pyVjDu8PwzWgXeLrv1XLkspXDSpJVeJLAG4q8UiuSjjPvXr3DcAtUk2YQF/OTdJMfVl3YcoSN+W7+yS5HfH+x2zN7u/OurvFyLg+1YRJFy4W9GxnBu09oHyMVOTEivfNW2aaX7rPqlwXRK4jdB67m+gKBlisllQEAAA==)